# Define a new ObjectSchema in jade

Tags: java, schema, message, agents-jade

I'm working with [jade](http://jade.tilab.com/) and have some agents which [communicate](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer4.html) with each other. I can design new messagetypes like for example a bookinfo `(String name, float prize, boolean availible)`. But I can only create messages with these basic variables like in this example:

```
ConceptSchema cs = (ConceptSchema) getSchema(BOOKINFO);
cs.add(NAME, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.STRING), ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
cs.add(PRIZE, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.FLOAT), ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
cs.add(AVAILIBLE, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.BOOLEAN), ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
```

This is how I define the Message in the [Ontology](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/Ontologies.htm)

But now I want to send an `ArrayList` (e.g. bookinfo `(String name, float prize, arrayList authers)`).

What I want is something like:

```
ConceptSchema cs = (ConceptSchema) getSchema(BOOKINFO);
cs.add(NAME, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.STRING), ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
cs.add(PRIZE, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.FLOAT), ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
cs.add(AUTHERS, **ObjectSchema-of-an-arrayList**, ObjectSchema.MANDATORY);
```

Where **ObjectSchema-of-an-arrayList** has to be defined so I can use it in the code. So I have to create an [ObjectSchema](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/content/schema/ObjectSchema.html) for the `ArrayList`.

I have searched hours for this problem but didn't found any solution. Can anybody help me?

Regards
Hans

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send an Object inside a message? You could pass the ArrayList as an Object and then the receiver could cast it back to ArrayList for using. Just giving an idea since I am not fluent in jade (I used mason sometime ago).